# Nested command and pipe command in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, grep, nested

I'm trying a few tests, in a shell script as below:

```
line="100:xx"
echo "$line" | grep -Po \\d+
```

**result: 100**

but,

```
line="100:xx"
echo `echo "$line" | grep -Po \\d+`
```

**result is empty**

Why?

Comment: is `echo "$line"` displaying the correct value? How about: `line="100:xx" echo \`echo "$line" | grep -Po \\d+\``

Comment: Because you are using backticks instead of `$()` and they suck.

Comment: It's in the escaping of the backslash. Try `echo \`echo "$line" | grep -Po \\\\d+\`` or `echo \`echo "$line" | grep -Po '\\d+'\`` (But do switch to `$()`, backticks have been deprecated for a long time.)

Comment: thank everybody, way of @Biffen working correct for me

Answer (score 5):

Because backticks allow expansions like double quoted strings, one of your backslashes is being eaten too soon:

```
$ echo `echo "$line" | grep -Po \\d+ | cat`

$ echo `echo "$line" | grep -Po \\\d+`
100
```

That being said, just quote the regex

```
$ echo `echo "$line" | grep -Po '\d+'`
100
```

Comment: Using single quotes around the regex is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this too:

```
echo $(echo "$line" | grep -Po \\d+)
```

to avoid your backslash being get eaten.

Comment: Really? Backticks have better results than nested POSIX with pipes.

Comment: @Sandburg : Stop using backticks and start using $() instead. This is the new standard...